# recreate design in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I recreate this text effect in CSS if the text is variable and I don't know the length of it each time? (it comes from a CMS)

I also want the background to have a slight opacity, but not the text.

[image: screenshot of text]

Comment: Besides the artefacts caused by the compression of the image I can't see any special text-effect?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the CMS spits that text out with <p> tags, meaning they are both the same length when they come out

Comment: Simply change the P tags to be 'inline-block' and style them with the orange background and opacity as mentioned below by others.

Comment: ok, I've done that, now they show up side by side i.imgur.com/XfTOZ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two divs with padding. Background would use rgba so you could control opacity. For example:

```
div { padding: 10px; background: rgba(255,255,255,.5) }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the CMS spits that text out with <p> tags, meaning they are both the same length when they come out

Comment: ok, I've done that, now they show up side by side i.imgur.com/XfTOZ.png

Comment: Are you able to wrap the p's in divs?

Comment: You could also float both p's left and have the second one clear:left

Answer (score 2):

For the transparent background:

```
<element>{
    background-color: rgba(255,102,0,.75);
}
```

the last value `a` is the opacity. To make it work in Internet-Explorer, use a filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#BFFF6600,endColorstr=#BFFF6600);
zoom: 1;
```

The first two hex-digits are the opacity (`0 = 00, 100% = FF`), the last 6 the color in hexvalues.

To make the paragraphs exaclty the same length as the text they contain, use the following:

```
p{
   display:inline-block;
   padding: <at will>;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the CMS spits that text out with <p> tags, meaning they are both the same length when they come out

Comment: ok, I've done that, now they show up side by side

http://i.imgur.com/XfTOZ.png

Comment: @Kevin then you could try: `float:left;clear:left;` instead of the `display:inline-block`

Comment: cheers buddy that worked a peach (going to test in different browsers now)

Answer (score 0):

Give an inline or inline-block element a semi-transparent background and a little padding. The semi-transparency is easiest with RGBA colors. (See http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba for browser compatibility).

Example:

```
.text
{
    display: inline;
    background-color: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6XUh7/